# Sending verticies to shader dynamically? (without glGenBuffers) Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

So, i have a vertex array and a bunch of attributes(Vertex pos, color, normal, uvs...) but is there a way to send the data without attributes or generating buffers every frame? Or is there a better way to do it? (To be specific, im making a batch rendering system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the buffer once and reupload the data to that buffer each frame.

This is done with [`glBufferSubData`](http://docs.gl/gl2/glBufferSubData). You will not need to rebind the attributes.